# Using regex for "W o.R-d".replaceAll("word", "replacement")

Tags: java, regex

My objective is to have a censoring. Currently atm I use message.replaceAll("(?i)word", "replacement") but this only catches the words which are not split up.

To bypass this people simply add a different character between the censored word.

So I want to have "Anyone else want to Y.O.L.O" turned into "Anyone else want to party" while just looking for 'yolo'. Keeping the '.' in there would be a bonus.

Comment: Dont understand your question properly.

Comment: Regex is not the way to go. What about (quoting from Austin Powers) someone writes "Fook yu!". Any regex can easily be bypassed

Comment: so basically you want to convert `Y.O.L.O` into `yolo`. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Obscenity filters don't work. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

Comment: I know that, but it still helps cut down the offensive chatter. And when the chatter himself doesn't have his message censored. Its pretty effective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How about:** (to replace "word" with "replacement")

```
msg.replaceAll("(?i)([^A-Za-z])w[^A-Za-z]?o[^A-Za-z]?r[^A-Za-z]?d([^A-Za-z])",
               "$1replacement$2") );
```

`[^A-Za-z]` is not a letter
`[^A-Za-z]?` is not a letter (optional)
`$1` is the first thing in brackets (first `([^A-Za-z])`)
`$2` is the first thing in brackets (last `([^A-Za-z])`)

**An alternative is look-around:**

```
msg.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=[^A-Za-z])w[^A-Za-z]?o[^A-Za-z]?r[^A-Za-z]?d(?=[^A-Za-z])",
               "replacement") );
```

It would not be difficult to generate the above automatically given a word.

Now that it's posted on the internet, everyone can see it and change their spamming to not get picked up by the above.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**EDIT:** I removed `\\b` (word boundary) since 1word2 will get skipped.

Comment: Ah so there is no way to just feed it a grouped string? Such as "yolo" instead of "y<regex>o<regex>"

Comment: @libraryaddict I doubt it.